# Returning from global variable after value set inside "load or error"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make `function` that will check for valid `image url` and return `true` / `false` depending upon the `valid url`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IsValidImageUrl(url) {
    var valval = '1';
    jQuery("<img>", {
        src: url,
        error: function(valval) { valval = '1'; alert('ERROR'); },
        load: function(valval) { valval = '0'; alert('Success'); }
    });
    alert(valval);
    return valval;
}
</script>
```

But, even on `Success`, it returns value of `valval` as `1`. It doesnot set value of `valval` as `0`.

Comment: Both error and load are callbacks ... means they are functions that are called later ... 
Your should call a function inside them so everything works in proper time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use callback for your purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IsValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    jQuery("<img>", {
        src: url,
        error: function() { callback(1); },
        load: function() { callback(0); }
    });
}

//usage
IsValidImageUrl('text.jpg', function (val){
    if (val == 0)
        alert('success');
    if (val == 1)
        alert('error');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you return the value before the request is even done. I'd set up some callbacks here, like this:

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    var valval = '1';
    jQuery("<img>", {
        src: url,
        error: function(valval) { callback('1') },
        load: function(valval) { callback('0') }
    });
}
```